# Unable to pass variable from .tf file to .json policy template

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I'm a newbe to terraform world and experiencing some tough time around passing variables from .tf file to .json
My sample tf lambda function is as follows

```
data "template_file" "task" {
  template = file("./iam/grange_rest_dynlambda_policy.json")
  vars = {
    resource="${var.stage}_grange_dynamodb"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "grange_rest_dynlambda" {
  function_name                  = "${var.stage}_grange_rest_dynlambda"
  handler                        = "lambda/src/index.handler"
  memory_size                    = "256"
  timeout                        = 10
  reserved_concurrent_executions = "-1"
  filename                       = "${path.module}/../dist/lambda.zip"
  role    = aws_iam_role.grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role.arn
  runtime = "nodejs14.x"
  publish = true
}

resource "aws_lambda_alias" "grange_rest_dynlambda_alias" {
  depends_on       = ["aws_lambda_function.grange_rest_dynlambda"]
  name             = var.stage
  description      = var.stage
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.grange_rest_dynlambda.arn
  function_version = aws_lambda_function.grange_rest_dynlambda.version
}

// Enable cloudwatch for lambda
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "example" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/${var.stage}_grange_rest_dynlambda"
  retention_in_days = 14
}

# See also the following AWS managed policy: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_logging" {
  name        = "lambda_logging"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging from a lambda"
  policy = file("./iam/grange_rest_dynlambda_logging_policy.json")
}

// Lambda + DynamoDB
resource "aws_iam_role" "grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role" {
  name               = "grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role"
  assume_role_policy = file("./iam/grange_rest_dynlambda_assume_policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_policy" {
  policy = file("./iam/grange_rest_dynlambda_policy.json")
  role   = aws_iam_role.grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role.id
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_logs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging.arn
}

// API Gateway + Lambda
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "grange_rest_dynlambda_api" {
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.grange_rest_api_gateway.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "grange_rest_dynlambda_api"
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.grange_rest_api_gateway.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "grange_rest_dynlambda_api_get" {
  authorization = "NONE"
  http_method   = "GET"
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.grange_rest_dynlambda_api.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.grange_rest_api_gateway.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "grange_rest_dynlambda_api_post" {
  authorization = "NONE"
  http_method   = "POST"
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.grange_rest_dynlambda_api.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.grange_rest_api_gateway.id
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.grange_rest_dynlambda.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.grange_rest_api_gateway.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.apigwdeployment.invoke_url
}
```

I inject policy from a JSON file and expect "resource" variable to be passed into JSON. But, that's not how it works

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
      "dynamodb:GetItem",
      "dynamodb:Query",
      "dynamodb:Scan",
      "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
      "dynamodb:PutItem",
      "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:741573820784:table/${resource}"
  }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Any errors?

Comment: This section in JSON does not get passed from TF file.Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:741573820784:table/${resource}"

Comment: You should be using the `templatefile` function instead as of version 0.12.0. That could very well fix the entire issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `template_file` data source does *not* replace the variables in the actual file. It just reads the file and provides the "rendered" output directly to your Terraform.

Therefore, you need to change your Terraform where you want to consume the "rendered" output:

Before:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_policy" {
  policy = file("./iam/grange_rest_dynlambda_policy.json")
  role   = aws_iam_role.grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role.id
}
```

After:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_policy" {
  policy = data.template_file.task.rendered
  role   = aws_iam_role.grange_rest_dynlambda_iam_role.id
}
```

You need to access the `rendered` property of the `template_file` data source:

```
data.template_file.task.rendered
```

This will replace `${resource}` with the value of `"${var.stage}_grange_dynamodb"`.

Please note, that the documentation recommends to use the [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) *function* instead of this data source.

Comment: Thanks @Jens. That worked. But now, I need something more. I take a leaf from your advice :). How do I convert this example above to "templatefile"?

Comment: @KrishnanSriram please try yourself and if you have problems ask another question here on SO.